# "service asterisk start" on fedora 17

Tags: bash, service, fedora, asterisk

I work with asterisk 11.2.1 and Fedora 17. I want to start asterisk by command "service asterisk start" and stop it "service asterisk stop".In other word  I want  to start asterisk itself when load OS

Comment: If you've installed from source make sure you do `make config` which will add it as a service and start asterisk at boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
systemctl start asterisk
```

and to stop:

```
systemctl stop asterisk
```

Enables a service to be started on bootup:

```
systemctl enable foo.service
```

Disables a service to not start during bootup:

```
systemctl disable foo.service
```

Comment: I want write service for asterisk in /etc/rc.d/init.d

Comment: I edited, with enable command